# How to query History table if a status is not found?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an `ORDERS` table, each `ORDER_ID` can have multiple statuses.

```
ORDER_ID |    STATUS
---------|-------------
1001     |    Requested
1001     |     Approved
1001     |     Invoiced
1001     |     Received
1001     |    Delivered
1011     |    Requested
1011     |     Approved
1011     |     Invoiced
1011     |    Delivered
```

I need to identify the `ORDER_ID`s that have a Delivered `STATUS` but not Received `STATUS`.

ex: Below order doesn't have Received status.

```
ORDER_ID
--------
1011
```

I tried to query using `group by having count < 5` , but it doesn't work
I tried to get all orders that are `Delivered` status in inner query, and tried to get the orders which are `Delivered` status but not `Received`. which is also not working. something like below

```
select order_id from orders where status !=Received and order_id in 
(select order_id from orders where status==delivered)
```

what is right query ?

Comment: Can you provide a sample output? Are you looking for a list of distinct Order Ids that meet your conditions? Or do you also want the applicable Statuses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using conditional aggregation.

```
select order_id 
from orders
group by order_id
having count(case when status='Delivered' then 1 end) > 0
and count(case when status='Received' then 1 end) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle supports the [`MINUS`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm) operator.

```
SELECT order_id
FROM orders
WHERE status = 'Delivered'
MINUS
SELECT order_id
FROM orders
WHERE status = 'Received'
```

Note: Someone else provided this answer before I did, but deleted it?

Answer (score 0):

I would use `NOT EXISTS` :

```
SELECT o.*
FROM orders o
WHERE STATUS = 'Delivered' AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM orders o1 WHERE o1.order_id = o.order_id AND o1.STATUS = 'Received');
```